# what does small scalar multiplication in ECC means?

Tags: elliptic-curves

I came across this table a lot in many articles, but I didn't understand what's the difference between Scalar multiplication operation in a group based on ECC and a Small scalar point multiplication operation in a group based on ECC ?

Source of table is from this [article](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/stamp/stamp.jsp?arnumber=8726296)

[image: Cryptographic operation time]

Comment: First, source of the table? second, for some small scaler, there are special formulas like 2 (doubling) and 3...

Comment: @kelalaka what do you mean by there are special formulas like 2 (doubling) and 3?

Comment: [Point doubling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_curve_point_multiplication#Point_doubling)

Comment: I've looked at the article and saw that the exact meaning belongs to them!

Comment: @kelalaka Yeah and that's what confused me :/ They used MIRACL library for this do you know another library like MIRACL but for python ?